# Wait-Notify synchronized by the same object doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I made this sample to understand how Wait-Notify works:

```
public class WaitingTest implements Runnable {

    Thread b = new Thread();
    int total;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        WaitingTest w = new WaitingTest();
    }

    public WaitingTest(){
        b.start();
            synchronized(b){
                try{
                    System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                    b.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(b){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            b.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck here for hours and I can't understand why it's not quite working. My output should be more than 0, but its always zero...I was wondering if its becuase of the usage of different threads, but Im not really sure..What am I missing?

Comment: Try start the thread =)

Comment: Could you tell us where do you think your `run` method should be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have some serious holes in your understanding. You've declared a `Thread`

```
Thread b = new Thread();
```

and started it in the constructor

```
b.start();
```

That `Thread` will start and die right away since it has no `Runnable` attached to it.

It just so happens that when a `Thread` dies, it calls `notify()` on itself and since you are `synchronized` on that same `Thread` object, your `wait()`ing thread will be awoken. You also have a race here. If the `Thread` ends before the main thread reaches the `wait()`, you will be deadlocked.

Also, there is no reason for `run()` to be called, which is why `total` remains 0.

---

Any object can be `synchronized` on, it doesn't have to be a `Thread`. And since `Thread` has that weird behavior of `notify()`ing itself, you probably shouldn't use it.

You should go through both the `Thread` [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) and the [synchronization tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: the run attachment comes from ``Thread b = new Thread(this);`` then - I will take a look on the tutorials, thx

Comment: @Victor You're welcome. Yes, you would have to pass `this` instance (or another `Runnable`) to the `Thread` constructor for it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problem with how you have arranged your threads, you have a incorrect use of wait()/notify()

notify() is stateless.  If no thread is waiting, nothing will be notified. If you wait() later it will not be notified.

wait() can wake spuriously.  Just because wait() woke doesn't mean anything notified it.

This means you need to associate wait/notify with state (in fact it's rather pointless without it)

For example.

```
 // to notify
 synchronized(lock) {
     signalled = true;
     lock.notify();
 }

 // to wait
 synchronized(lock) {
     while(!signalled)
          lock.wait();
 }
```

Comment: I was wondering also this, If i call ``b.notify();`` right after the sync, the value for total should be zero, but somehow it isn't..